# Подсчет значений в двух и более столбцах одним запросом через PDO Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Предстала предо мною задача сделать возможность подсчета количества одинаковых значений в двух столбцах (через SQL запрос `SELECT COUNT(*)`), использую для построения запросов к базе возможности библиотеки PDO.

Суть проблемы состоит в том, что PDO выводит количество одинаковых значений только в одном столбце, количество одинаковых значений в другом столбце PDO напрочь отказывается выводить (просто не выводит), единственным выходом из положения является составление SQL запроса для каждого столбца отдельно, но я хочу, что бы все это поместилось в один запрос.

Пример кода, который я использую

```
$enter = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE row='value' AND row1='value1'";
$fetch_info = $db->query($enter)->fetch();
print_r($fetch_info);
```

В массив попадает значение только одного столбца. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Боярин PDO плохой, царь SQL хороший. Тут не в PDO дело, SQL сам по себе такие штуки не позволяет. Можете сделать два подзапроса в виде `SELECT (SELECT xxx) AS field_a, (SELECT yyy) AS field_b`.

Comment: Пожалуй вы правы, по факту получается одним запросом проблему не решить...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что ты не понимаешь языка SQL и, как следствие, запрашиваешь у БД не то что тебе надо.

Твой запрос не считает "количество одинаковых записей в первом столбце", что бы это ни значило. Он считает количество строк, одновременно удовлетворяющих условиям `row='value'` и `row1='value1'`

Если тебе нужно посчитать количество строк, которые удовлетворяют условию `row='value'` и отдельно - условию `row1='value1'`,  то проще это сдеать двумя запросами.

Кстати,  полезная информация:
Если мы запрашиваем одиночное значение, то можно получить его сразу, минуя массив:

```
$count = $db->query($enter)->fetchColumn();
```

Comment: Вы правы, я плохо понимаю язык SQL, но наконец то я решил свою проблему сам. В любом случае, ваш ответ заслуживает отметки "Лучший ответ"...